# C++ won't let me make a private constructor (or how can I simulate this usage)

Tags: c++, inheritance, sdl-2

I need to make a private constructor so anything that inherits the class does not call the constructor again. For example:

```
class Main
{
    private:
        Main()
        {
            std::cout << "Main Constructor called\n";
            SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
            window = SDL_CreateWindow("Program", 0, 30, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE );
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );

            running = true;
        }


        ~Main()
        {
            std::cout << "Main Destructor called\n";
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

            SDL_Quit();
        }

    public:
        SDL_Window* window;
        SDL_Renderer* renderer;
        SDL_Event event;
        bool running;

};
```

anything now that inherits the class `Main` (atleast I think) won't call the constructor? If this isn't the case how can I obtain the same usage such that my `Main` constructor is only called ONCE. (error is `error: 'Main::Main()' is private`

Comment: Does `Rectangle` extend `Main` or do you just want to use `Main`'s members?

Comment: you have `Main m;` and `Rectangle rectangle;` which makes a total of 2 calls to constructor of `Main`. Please clarify, include output and expected output in the question

Comment: Forgive me im pretty new to this, but is there a difference between extending and using mains members? What would extending main allow me to do verses using Mains members. ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, I would prefer if I could just have one call of Main's constructor, how can I achieve this, (as well as using Rectangle class)

Comment: your question is not quite clear. Please add the output and expected output, and explain why you inherit `Rectangle` from `Main`

Comment: you can edit your question via [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65806978/edit). Comments get overlooked easily and are rather for shortlived clarifications

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 how can I access ```Main```'s members without calling its constructor?

Comment: @asdfgodsia123e890dik The base class constructor will always be called once for every instance that you create, even when constructing derived objects. Maybe you are looking for something like a singleton?

Comment: Sure, ill have a look at that, basically, I want a ```Main``` class and then anything about it I need (say im making a rectangle class, when I want to draw a rectangle im going to need the SDL_Renderer but I need it to be in the rectangle class to access too)

Comment: @super also, with the singleton (just had a look), I need the constructor to call all those functions to initialise SDL2, and its destructor to free them (destroy the SDL2 memory)

Answer (score 0):

Your other class should not inherit from `Main`. they might have reference to it (either as member or as parameter of function call).

`Main` constructor might be public:

```
class Main
{
public:
    Main()
    {
        assert(running == false);
        std::cout << "Main Constructor called\n";
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Program", 0, 30, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE );
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );

        running = true;
    }

    Main(const Main&) = delete;
    Main(Main&&) = delete;
    Main& operator=(const Main&) = delete;
    Main& operator=(Main&&) = delete;

    ~Main()
    {
        std::cout << "Main Destructor called\n";
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

        SDL_Quit();
        running = false;
    }

public:
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;
    SDL_Event event;
    static bool running;
};
static bool Main::running = false;

struct Rectangle
{
    Point bottomLeft;
    Point topRight;
};

void Draw(Main&, const Rectangle&);
```

Comment: With that, how can I have other classes that use member variables from Main without passing in a reference? For example, if I have multiple files, I don't have to keep doing ```#include "main.h"``` to use all of mains information?

Comment: With your inheritance, you have to "#include main.h". With pointer/reference, forward declaration might be enough, and just files using member have to do the `#include`.

Comment: Ah okay, other thing is, i'm not really sure I understand what all of those lines where you have ```Main&... = delete;```

Comment: Oh and also, with singletons as ive just discovered, you can make it so when you declare ```Main``` you can only ever get a reference to it, you cannot create an instance of it (only 1 will ever be created). How can I do the same here with main so I dont accidently create an instance of it?

Comment: the `=delete` is to forbid the call to those method. `Singleton` is mostly a anti-pattern.